# Retrieve information from configuration file in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm working on my second bigger programming project at the moment and I got stuck. I'm using Processing for this project.

What I'm trying to do is retrieve information (used to assign a certain color palette to the individual 'lines' of a horizontal bar chart) from an external text file that contains the following line, using an instance of the java.util.Properties class:

```
formating = p;p;n;n
```

My code snippet for importing it looks like this (using a class named 'Import' that handles the BufferedInputStream, etc.):

```
Import imp = new Import();
Properties properties = imp.importSettings();
```

The next step reads the 'formating' line from the text file and puts it into a four element String array, using the Semicolon as a delimiter.

```
String[] formating = properties.getProperty("formating").split(";");
```

I was expecting for this String array to be identical to the one I would get by creating it in my source code using:

```
String[] formating2 = {"p", "p", "n", "n"};
```

But it isn't. It tried a number of things already, including checking for unwanted characters (blanks for example) in each element of my String array, converting my text file or the characters I use for comparison to Unicode, converting the elements of the String array to Chars.

What I can't seem to get working is the following comparison:

```
for(int i=0;i < formating.length;i++){
println(formating[i]==formating2[i]);
}
```

which returns 'false' for each iteration of the for-loop.

I'm sure it's just some rookie mistake but it would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comparing strings using == is not safe since Strings are possibly different objects and comparing them, no matter if they contain the same "text" does not compare the texts but the objects. So, you should try it like this:

```
println(formating[i].equals(formating2[i]));
```

or if you want to avoid excess spaces and tabs all-together you can also do:

```
println(formating[i].trim().equals(formating2[i].trim()));
```